# Load testing a complex workflow

Tags: performance, performance-testing

I want to load test a website. The website is used mainly to submit picture albums and has two main worflows:

One workflow for user registration:

1. Create a new account
2. Enter username, password, email address
3. Agree to the terms
4. Upload an avatar picture

Another workflow to submit albums:

1. Login
2. Create a new album with name, location, etc.
3. Upload a picture
4. Tag picture
5. Repeat from 3 (0 to n times)
6. Submit

These workflows take quite some time to execute (submitting a new album takes up to 5 minute). If I want to generate 1 album submission per second, I would have 5 * 60 = 300 threads running.

Also there is constraint on the data:

- A user cannot have two albums with the same name
- A picture cannot be uploaded twice or by two different users

I am wondering how other websites with similar workflows have been load tested and what is the recommended approach.

Answer (score 0):

Test Data is very important for any performance testing, the Test data used could within the application has to be unique or duplicate could work.

In your application it has to be Unique, so I recommend you need to create test data separately for each scenario with the sufficient number of records available to complete each transaction, without any interdependence.

For albums names, you can create the unique name to append the data & time within your script, for example - TData_0605_1205

Similarly, you need to build a good amount of Image repository that can last for 300 * total load test time(mins), the naming convention for these images can be incremental, say TImage1, TImage2, TImage3............TImagen , within your script, write a logic to pick the images in sequential fashion with incremental of 1, this number you can get from the thread count/iteration count depending on how you script your framework.

Hope this helps.

​​Thanks,
Bhaskar 
Technical Head
Thought Frameworks Inc
C: +1-619-630-5034